# Socket events significantly delayed when server tick rate drops below 1000

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, three.js

I'm working on a game with server-authoritative multiplayer, and as such the server calculates player positions in real-time on every tick() and replicates them to all clients.

Example:

```
var broadcastRate = 60;
var lastBroadcast = 0;
function tick() {

    var deltaTime = clock.getDelta();
    lastBroadcast += deltaTime;

    var newPositions = recalculatePositions(deltaTime);

    // Broadcast updates 60 times per second
    if (lastBroadcast*broadcastRate > 1) {
        io.sockets.emit('update', newPositions);
        lastBroadcast = 0;
    }

    setImmediate(tick);
}
```

In addition, the server handles socket.on() events from players telling the server their new direction.

In addition to the above I'm keeping track of the server's tick rate, which drops as more players join (due to calculatePositions() taking longer) or as the game's geometry becomes more complex (due to collision detection taking longer).

I noticed that when the tick rate drops too low, around <1000, the socket.on and the socket.emit events start becoming significantly delayed and do not fire right away when called. This causes a huge (several second) delay in the client receiving an updated position from the server upon pressing a key, even with a ping of zero.

This shouldn't be the case; a server with a tick rate even of only 100 should perform just fine, so I'm wondering what is causing the delay in socket events firing? Does this have something to do with setImmediate(tick), or do I need to change something with the sockets to force them to fire immediately?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: don't know much about `setImmediate` but have you tried other methods like `nextTick` for example ?

Comment: The *lastBroadcast\*broadcastRate > 1* line looks fishy to me. You could in principle easily end up with values >> 1 and then you'd silently be dropping seconds worth of updates that simply don't get sent out. Have you tried checking what the actual value for *lastBroadcast\*broadcastRate* is when it's > 1?